# `Total1` variable has the same output as `DealerTotal` variable, when they should be different

Tags: python, variables, blackjack

This is my modified version of Blackjack.

I'm still new to Python, so there's a lack of formatting in this program and serious rule modification, but what I don't understand is if you were to run this program why `Total1` has the same output as `DealerTotal`.

In Phase 1, if you just pass and confirm that you're passing, everything works out smoothly. You have your own total, which is the sum of `Card1` and `Card2` and the dealer has his own total (which I'm cheating and having him hit 3 times): `Card1`, `Card2`, `Card3`. So everything works fine in `PHASE 1`.

But when I enter `PHASE 2`, doing the same process (passing & confirming) makes the `Total1` and `DealerTotal` output identical.

Why does the `DealerTotal` in `PHASE 1` work, but the `DealerTotal` in `PHASE 2` not even when the code is identical?

```
# Imports
import random
import sys

# Dictionary
Cards = {"1": 1, "2": 2, "3": 3, "4": 4, "5": 5, "6": 6, "7": 7, "8": 8, "9": 9,
         "10": 10, 'Jack': 10, 'Queen': 10, 'King': 10, 'Ace': 10}

# Welcome Print
print('Welcome to Blackjack!\n\nHere are your cards: \n ')
# Cards
keys = list(Cards)
# Beginning Cards
Card1 = random.choice(keys)
Card2 = random.choice(keys)
# Hit 1 Card
Card3 = random.choice(keys)
# Hit 2 Card
Card4 = random.choice(keys)
# Hit 3 Card
Card5 = random.choice(keys)
# Hit 4 Card
Card6 = random.choice(keys)
# Hit 5 Card
Card7 = random.choice(keys)
# Hit 6 Card
Card8 = random.choice(keys)

# Sum of Cards
# Beginning Total
Total = Cards[Card1] + Cards[Card2]
# Hit 1 Total
Total1 = Total + Cards[Card3]
# Hit 2 Total
Total2 = Total1 + Cards[Card4]
# Hit 3 Total
Total3 = Total2 + Cards[Card5]
# Hit 4 Total
Total4 = Total3 + Cards[Card6]
# Dealer's Total
DealerTotal = Cards[Card1] + Cards[Card2] + Cards[Card3]



### BEGINNING ###
print(Card1, 'and a', Card2, '. Your total is', Total)


### PHASE 1 ###
Choice = input('Would you like to hit or pass? (h = hit, p = pass): ')
# Hitting PHASE 1
if (Choice == 'h'):
    print('The dealer gives you a', Card3, '. Your new total is: '  , Total1)
    # Hitting & Losing HIT 1
    if (Total1 > 21):
        print('You lose! Try again later.')
        sys.exit()
# Passing PHASE 1
if (Choice == 'p'):
    # Confirmation whether you want to pass/hit
    Response1 = input('Are you sure? The dealer may have a better hand. (y = yes, n = no): ')
    # Reponse to hitting 'y'
    if (Response1 == 'y'):
        print('Your total is', Total, "The dealer's total is", DealerTotal)
        if (DealerTotal > 21 or 21 >= Total > DealerTotal):
            print("Congratulations, you've won!")
            sys.exit()
        elif (DealerTotal == Total):
            print('You have tied!')
        else:
            print('You lose! Try again later.')
            sys.exit()


### PHASE 2 ###
Choice1 = input('Would you like to hit or pass? (h = hit, p = pass): ')
# Hitting PHASE 2
if (Choice1 == 'h'):
    print('The dealer gives you a', Card4, '. Your new total is: ' , Total2)
    # Hittnig & Losing HIT 2
    if (Total2 > 21):
        print('You lose! Try again later.')
        sys.exit()
# Passing PHASE 2
if (Choice1 == 'p'):
    # Confirmation whether you want to pass/hit
    Response2 = input('Are you sure? The dealer may have a better hand.(y = yes, n = no): ')
    # Reponse to hitting 'y'
    if (Response2 == 'y'):
        print('Your total is', Total1, "The dealer's total is", DealerTotal)
        if (DealerTotal > 21 or 21 >= Total1 > DealerTotal):
            print("Congratulations, you've won!")
            sys.exit()
        elif (DealerTotal == Total1):
            print('You have tied!')
        else:
            print('You lose! Try again later.')
            sys.exit()
```

Comment: You have `Total = Cards[Card1] + Cards[Card2]; Total1 = Total + Cards[Card3]` and `DealerTotal = Cards[Card1] + Cards[Card2] + Cards[Card3]`. Basically, you have `x = a + b; x = x + c` and `y = a + b + c`. Why do you expect them to different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of the logic that you have written.

```
Total = Cards[Card1] + Cards[Card2]
Total1 = Total + Cards[Card3]
```

Replacing the value of Total

```
Total1 = Cards[Card1] + Cards[Card2] + Cards[Card3]
```

and

```
DealerTotal = Cards[Card1] + Cards[Card2] + Cards[Card3]
```

as you can probably see, DealerTotal = Total1, that is why they are coming as identical.

Answer (score 2):

This might sound dumb, but the reason Total1 has the same value as DealerTotal is because Total1 has the same value as DealerTotal.

You assign the variables at the start of the program and then never touch them again. Total1 is `Total1 = Total + Cards[Card3]`. Total is `Total = Cards[Card1] + Cards[Card2]`. So, Total1 is equivalent to: `Cards[Card1] + Cards[Card2] + Cards[Card3]`.

Now let's look at DealerTotal: `DealerTotal = Cards[Card1] + Cards[Card2] + Cards[Card3]`. Seem familiar?

This isn't happening in Phase 1 because you're using `Total` for the comparison, rather than `Total1`

Comment: Thank you! I managed to fix the problem and complete the game.